# How can I exclude all Jetpack Compose's Preview functions from Jacoco report?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, code-coverage, jacoco

When we run Jacoco code coverage of Jetpack Compose function, I like to exclude all Preview functions.

I can do so using

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
internal annotation class ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport
```

Then for the function I like to exclude from the report, I annotate it with

```
@ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport
@Preview(
    name = "Name"
)
@Composable
private fun MyComposePreview() {
    // ... function content
}
```

This works. But I have to add the annotation to all my Preview functions.
I am hoping I can do it in the build.gradle file to exclude them all.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Preview says that it can be applied to:

> Annotation classes, that could then be used to annotate @Composable methods or other annotation classes, which will then be considered as indirectly annotated with that Preview.

So I suppose you could create an annotation "PreviewExludedFromJacoco" that you annotate with Preview. This is not exactly what you ask for, but it would allow you to have only one annotation for each Preview function.